# Is $\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_{2}^{\aleph_0}$ equivalent to the Continuum Hypothesis?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

While searching for exercises dealing with **CH** and **GCH**, I encountered an exercise with the following statement:

> Study if:
>
> $\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_{2}^{\aleph_0}$
>
> Is equivalent to the Continuum Hypothesis

My first thought is that the statement has nothing to do with **CH** for it only gives a relation between $\aleph_{1}$ and $2^{\aleph_{0}}$.

I am getting started with this topic, so if you could give a clear and full answer, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: deleted part of the original question, as it was pretty ill-posed

Comment: If CH is true, then $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1\lt \aleph_2 \leq \aleph_2^{\aleph_0}$. So CH certainly implies the inequality.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But if we claim that instead, that there is an equality, are we denying CH?

Comment: Yes... but that's just the contrapositive of what I just said! CH implies the inequality, so Not(inequality) implies Not(CH). That is not the question you should ask next however; the question that remains is whether the inequality implies CH, or if the negation of CH implies that the inequality is false.

Comment: Yes, my bad, that is what I tried to mean. I am really tired right now, so I'm not thinking clearly about any of this...

Comment: Be careful about the distinction between ordinal exponentiation and cardinal exponentiation. We have $2^\omega = \omega$ (this is ordinal exponentiation), but $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0$ (this is cardinal exponentiation), even though $\omega = \aleph_0$ as sets! The operation in your question is cardinal exponentiation, not ordinal exponentiation.

Comment: I think I got it: if we suppose that $\aleph_{1}<\aleph_{2}<2^{\aleph_{1}}$, then we have that $\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_{0}}\le\aleph_{2}^{\aleph_{0}}\le2^{\aleph_{1}\times\aleph_{0}}=2^{\aleph_{1}}$, so $\aleph_{2}\le\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_{0}}$, and rising to the power $\aleph_{0}$, we get that $\aleph_{2}^{\aleph_{0}}\le\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_{0}\times\aleph_{0}}=\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_{0}}$, so we get the equality. Is that right?

Comment: We can have $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2^{\aleph_0}$ in models of MA and non-CH, say with continuum equal to $\aleph_3$.

Comment: @Arthur There is a binary operation on the ordinals called [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation). Under this operation, $2^\omega = \omega$.

Comment: @Arthur For me, $2^{\omega}=sup\{2^n|n\in\omega\}$, because $\omega$ is a limit ordinal. In this context, $2^\omega$ is not the ordinal of the set of applications from $\omega$ to $2$ under some well-ordering relation on this set, but it is the ordinal of the well-ordered set of the functions from $\omega$ to $2$ that have finite support, under a relation that resembles some sort of lexicographic order from the right.

Comment: @AlexKruckman You're right, of course. I messed up my mental arithmetic.

Comment: After this digression into ordinal vs. cardinal exponientiation, can anyone please confirm that the solution I just gave in the comments is right?

Comment: Non(CH) does not imply $\aleph_2\lt 2^{\aleph_1}$, so I don't see how you justify that assumption.

Comment: Elaborating on @ArturoMagidin's comment, it is consistent with ZFC that $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$ (this is for example a consequence of the [proper forcing axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_forcing_axiom)).

Comment: @Akerbeltz No, that's not true: we could have CH$_{\aleph_1}$ hold even if CH itself fails. (Here "CH$_\kappa$" means "$2^\kappa=\kappa^+$," so e.g. CH$_{\aleph_1}$ means $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$; and usual CH is CH$_{\aleph_0}$ in this notation.)

Comment: You are confused about what CH says. CH just says that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$. It is entirely silent about what happens to $2^{\aleph_k}$ with $k\gt 0$. Even the negation of GCH would not guarantee that $2^{\aleph_1}\gt \aleph_2$.

Comment: How should I modify my argument to indeed demonstrate that the equality must hold?

Comment: Since your argument is incorrect from the very get-go, I would suggest discarding it entirely and trying from scratch, not trying to tweak it to get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to observe that $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$ regardless of whether CH holds. In particular, it's going to help in a bit to *not* simplify the right hand side.

---

Here's a proof of that observation:

- $\le$: immediate, since we know without assumptions that $\aleph_1\le 2^{\aleph_0}$ and raising both sides to $\aleph_0$ doesn't break $\le$.
- $\ge$: the right hand side simplifies to $2^{\aleph_0}$, and (by the same reasoning as the previous bullet) we know that $2^{\aleph_0}\le \aleph_1^{\aleph_0}$.

---

Now back to the main problem.

The comparison we're really trying to make is, by the observation above, $$(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}\mbox{ versus }(\aleph_2)^{\aleph_0}.$$

We know that we get "$<$" if CH holds. Now suppose CH fails; what does that tell us about $2^{\aleph_0}$ versus $\aleph_2$ (and hence, what does that tell us about the comparison we want to make)?

Comment: So if HC doesn't hold, $\aleph_{2}\le 2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: @Akerbeltz CH, but yes.

Comment: In Spanish it's all the way around, it's lame that comments can't be edited...

Answer (score 3):

Using Hausdorff formula we have $$\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}\cdot\aleph_2,$$
Now using the fact that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}\leq (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$, we get that $$\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}\cdot\aleph_2.$$

If $2^{\aleph_0}\geq\aleph_2$, then $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}$. Therefore, the assumption that $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}$ implies that CH holds.